# How to support WebAuthn in WKWebViews or on PWA based IOS app

Tags: progressive-web-apps, wkwebview, sfsafariviewcontroller, webauthn

I am using webauthn for biometric authentication like fingerprint scan in my pwa.
Now to publish it on IOS as an app I have used pwabuilder.com to get an ios package, which packages pwa to load it in wkwebview so that it can run on ios as native app. Now when I am running this pwa ios package using xcode everything is working fine except biometric login.
I checked online and it seems wkwebviews don't support webauthn. Is there any work around for this?

We tried using SFSafariViewerController and with this, webauthn works fine but once user presses done on safariviewercontroller UI it reaches back to login page so we will need to send some authentication information to WKWebView which initiated that SFSafariViewerController in order to authenticate user. Can anyone tell us how can we share the data between SFSafariViewerController and WKWebView?